# Selenium with Python: can't find element by link text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Could you help me understand why in this particular case find_element_by_partial_link_text doesn't catch the element.

from selenium import webdriver
import unittest

```
class RegisterNewUser(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.get("http://web.archive.org/web/20141117213704/http://demo.magentocommerce.com/")

    def test_register_new_user(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log In").click()
```

Pardon for the strange link. I'm reading a book on Selenium and the link was originally from there. But the contents has changed. The book seems Ok for me. So, I just extracted old web page from an archive.

Well, if I view page source, I can find the link there. But I can't reach it via Selenium.

Could you give me a hint? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is hidden, you will need to click first on the menu (`Account`)